# Firefox gives "301 Moved permanently" error on Http Request

Tags: json, angular, typescript, firefox

I am currently developping an Angular 4 chat application, which make severals HTTP request.

On Google Chrome or Opera browser, all requests work fine but when I test my app on Firefox, one of them doesn't pass. I have already cleared my cache many times but the problem persists.

```
this.chatWebService.getLatestConversations(params).subscribe(
    (response: CustomHttpResponse<ConversationModel[]>) => {
        this.chatSharedService.setDiscussionList(response.data);
    },
    (errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(errorResponse)
    });
```

And the request:

```
public getLatestConversations(p: { filter: string, search: string, page_index: number, page_count: number }): Observable<{}> {
    const url = `${this.messagesUrl}?filter=${p.filter}&search=${p.search}&page_index=${p.page_index}&page_count=${p.page_count}`;

    return this.http.get(url, { params: this.createHttpParams(p) });
}

private createHttpParams(params: {}): HttpParams {
    const searchParams = new HttpParams();
    const keys = Object.keys(params);
    keys.forEach(key => searchParams.append(key, String(params[key])));

    return searchParams;
}
```

On Firefox, this code gives me this error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data

[image: The error handler gives this error]

Here is a sample of the returned JSON data:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "user",
            "id": 76,
            "name": "User 1",
            "slug": "razx6k5nuser",
            "muted": false,
            "messages": [
                {
                    "content": "Hi there",
                    "media": false,
                    "sent": 1516372902,
                    "read": true,
                    "sender": {
                        "id": 76,
                        "slug": "razx6k5nuser",
                        "lastname": "User lastname",
                        "firstname": "User  first name",
                        "phoneNumber": ""
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "user",
            "id": 71,
            "name": "User 2",
            "slug": "volc6p1suser",
            "muted": false,
            "messages": [
                {
                    "content": "new message",
                    "media": false,
                    "sent": 1516358686,
                    "read": false,
                    "sender": {
                        "id": 77,
                        "slug": "razv6i2auser",
                        "lastname": "User lastname",
                        "firstname": "User first name",
                        "phoneNumber": ""
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "page": "1",
        "total": 18,
        "totalNotRead": 1,
        "totalMuted": 0
    }
}
```

According to some errors I found on Google, it seems be solved by adding some headers for each request, so I have already added some headers on each of request with the interceptor, like this:

```
const request = req.clone({
    setHeaders: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
});
```

But it still doesn't work. Can someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: could you add the angular code where you make the XHR request ? We cant help you without it.

Comment: Okey, I will update the post ... :)

Comment: @PierreMallet I have updated the post

Comment: So could you resolve this issue? @Laiso